# Need to transform values from a list into an attribute based on a set of rules

Tags: xslt, xsd, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have an XML transaction that has a container element (PURCHASELIST) that contains repeating DOLL elements, containing a NAME attribute (in this case, one NAME says "KEN" and one NAME says "BARBIE".

```
    <PURCHASELIST>
        <DOLL NAME="KEN"/>
        <DOLL NAME="BARBIE"/>
    </PURCHASELIST>
```

I want to transform the output so that the values in the NAME attributes are parsed into a BOX attribute with the following rules:

If only Ken is present, the attribute value is ‘KEN’.  If only Barbie is present, the attribute value is ‘BRB’.  If both Ken and Barbie are present, the attribute value is ‘ALL'.

Thus, in the case above, I want the RESULT element to have a BOX attribute equal to "ALL".

```
    <RESULT TYPE="DOLLIES" SIZE=”MIN” BOX=”ALL”/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 (both work)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="PURCHASELIST">
        <RESULT TYPE="DOLLIES" SIZE="MIN">
            <xsl:attribute name="BOX">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="count(DOLL[@NAME=('KEN', 'BARBIE')]) = 2">
                        <xsl:value-of select="'ALL'"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="DOLL[@NAME='KEN']">
                        <xsl:value-of select="'KEN'"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="DOLL[@NAME='BARBIE']">
                        <xsl:value-of select="'BRB'"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </RESULT>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

**[Working example](http://xsltransform.net/b4GWV2)**

Comment: Invalid XPath expression
Unexpected token - ", 'BARBIE')]) = 2"
test="count(DOLL[@NAME=('KEN', 'BARBIE')]) = 2"

Comment: I'm assuming that the syntax is slightly off.  I'm not able to test your solution in its current state in Altova XML Spy.

Comment: I was able to modify the first 'xsl:when' and get this to work by doing the following:

Comment: <xsl:when test="count(DOLL[@NAME='KEN']) = 1 and count(DOLL[ @NAME='BARBIE'] )= 1 ">
                                                            <xsl:value-of select="'A'"/>
                                                            </xsl:when>

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer because the basic premise was there.